# Where is the standard Java exceptions in Android platform?

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm wondering there is the standard Java exceptions like NullPointerException, InvalidArgumentException, etc... I can't find them accessible under Android platform.

Why the Android implemented this way? And if I'm developing some shared Android library, am I need to write my own exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) says that `NullPointerException` (and many others) are available in even early versions of the API. Where are you looking for them that you aren't finding them?

Comment: Shame on me! Didn't understand what i've typed to SDK search and can't find them... Also seems like i trying to find `InvalidArgumentException` instead of `IllegalArgumentException`...

Answer (score 0):

Something must be broken in your setup.

The Android SDK contains the standard java exceptions in the usual place, in the java.lang package.

For example (Android 1.5):
/platforms/android-3/android.jar

Answer (score 0):

[`java.lang.NullPointerException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is part of the *android API* - the dalvik vm is <strike>based on</strike> *inspired by* apache harmony which is an open source implementation of Java.

Comment: dalvik vm does not have a base, it is clean room. (So they can't be sued) . Though you are right, the class library is.